# javascript validate lang, lat to be in dmc format

Tags: javascript

I've two input fields that user must enter a lang,lat number and I want to validate that to be in specific format which is:

41°24’12.2

it starts with a number followed by degree sign followed by number followed by ’ followed by number followed by . followed by the last number

how to achieve that using Javascript?

Comment: Please visit [ask]. Show us what you have tried, where you have failed, then we may be able to help you.

Comment: You could use a regular expression ...

Comment: You should use regular expressions for validating inputs. Check [Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
let value = "41°24’12.2";
let regex = /^\d{2}°\d{2}’\d{2}\.\d$/;

console.log(regex.test(value));
```

Details here https://regexr.com/5bp76

But to break it down

- `^` start of string
- `\d{2}` two digits
- `°` literal °
- `’` literal ’
- `\.` literal `.`
- `\d` single digit
- `$` end of string

Answer (score 0):

```js
var lat = document.querySelector("#lat"),
  long = document.querySelector("#long");

lat.addEventListener("input", validate);
long.addEventListener("input", validate);
validate();

function validate() {
  [lat, long].forEach(function(dom) {
    dom.className = /^\d{1,2}°\d{1,2}’\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/.test(dom.value) ? "ok" : "bad";
  });
}
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

input.ok {
  border-color: green;
}

input.bad {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lat" placeholder="lat" />
<input type="text" id="long" placeholder="long" />
```